# nginx - How to read a file in location directive?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

How can I read a file within location directive? After reading the file, based on some decision I will proceed further or throw error.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do with default nginx build without extra modules. But you can do it with [`openresty`](https://openresty.org/en/) or [`lua-ngx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424483/nginx-lua-how-to-output-file/24428699#24428699) is an example.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for sharing the info. I tried openresty and it is very easy to use lua modules directly in nginx.conf file.